# How do I override a class variable in this gem's module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using the devise_saml_authenticatable gem for saml authentication with devise and would like to override the @@saml_default_resource_locator
variable on line 105 [here](https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable/blob/6b28e94a96dd11090163d56ce05c500e5047ee6e/lib/devise_saml_authenticatable.rb). I just want to add an extra where clause so that it's only looking at users of a certain type. I've overriden gem methods in the past (but never class variables) do doing putting something like this in an initializer:

```
RedCloth::Formatters::HTML.send(:include, GemExtensions::RedCloth::Formatters::HTML::Notextile)
```

But I'm not sure where to start in this instance. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to add a where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @chumakoff's answer will do the trick, I think that you do not have to and *shouldn't* patch the DeviseSamlAuthenticatable gem this way. The gem mainly calls the block configurable under the `Devise.saml_resource_locator` accessor when authenticating. And if this block is not set, it calls the `Devise.saml_default_resource_locator` block by default.

So, I guess **you should simply set the [`saml_resource_locator`](https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable/blob/6b28e94a96dd11090163d56ce05c500e5047ee6e/lib/devise_saml_authenticatable.rb#L113)**:

```
Devise.saml_resource_locator = Proc.new do |model, saml_response, auth_value|
  model.where(Devise.saml_default_user_key => auth_value).where(...).first
end
```

See also the specs for some [examples](https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable/blob/master/spec/devise_saml_authenticatable/model_spec.rb#L295).

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to change a class variable. There is the `class_variable_set` method that you can use. Or you can just open the module and define the variable again, or use `instance_eval`.

Put this code to initializers:

```
Devise.class_variable_set(
  :@@saml_default_resource_locator,
  Proc.new do |model, saml_response, auth_value|
    # whatever you want
  end
)
```

Or open the module and define the variable again:

```
module Devise
  @@saml_default_resource_locator = Proc.new do |model, saml_response, auth_value|
    # whatever you want
  end
end
```

Using `instance_eval`:

```
Devise.instance_eval do
  @@saml_default_resource_locator = Proc.new do |model, saml_response, auth_value|
    # whatever you want
  end
end
```